# Hidden Bluetooth/BLE Devices

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, sensors

When programming a BLE Device or Sensor - is it possible to make it 'hidden' from the phone's general bluetooth settings > add device? And then make it possible to be discovered/paired with only through a particular phone app.

To achieve this some suggested using a particular UUID and then the propriety app would filter for that particular UUID.

Answer (score 2):

The suggestion of @Kushal can work. But still, you can not hide your custom peripheral device in the phone's scan results.

You can hide your custom peripheral device's `BLE` name by removing the local name from the advertisement data. This way, your device will be seen as `Unknown Device` in the phone's scan results (or in any other central device). Then you filter the `UUID` of your custom peripheral device in your app and users can only see `your` custom peripheral device in the app.

Comment: Hi, however this would not work if I have multiple devices with the same custom UUID and I would like each device to have a different name/ID to be identifiable, correct?

Comment: The public address field (UUID) of a peripheral device is 48 bits long. Usually, you should set the first 24 bit of the UUID to a company defined constant number. Then you should generate unique 24 bits on each device for the other 24 bits. For example, Cypress lets you write a company-specific 24-bit at the most significant 24 bits, then it generates a unique 24 bits using the silicon id of the device. This way, you can filter the scan results by checking your 24-bit company-defined number, but also have unique UUIDs for each device you have.

Comment: +This way you also don't need to program different binary to every peripheral device, instead, the device will calculate the unique UUID dynamically for itself.

Comment: Hi abdullah, this is quite interesting... I will check it out thank you. Have you got any trusted resources/material about this? I'm stilk going to look it up myself. Just checking. Thanks, Luke

Comment: I don't have any material about this, maybe only the Cypress's BLE components datasheet. But you should be able to set the public device address to whatever you want in your custom device too. If it was forbidden, Cypress wouldn't allow it too. If you can set it yourself, then the rest of the job is to generate unique address numbers for your every device. In this step, Cypress suggests using the silicon id. But you can set the numbers manually too.

Comment: Hi Abdullah, I am not very experienced with ble however most UUIDs seem to be specified as 128 bit long. Then what are you referring to exactly since you referred to the public address field (UUID) as 48 bits long.

Comment: @LukeGalea UUID is to for identifying the characteristics or services. BLE address is a different thing, it is used for distinguishing BLE devices physically. It's like the MAC address of a BLE device. It is 48 bits long, you can set a constant 24 bit for the most-significant 24 bits as your company/organization id. Then set unique 24 bits for the least-significant 24 bits for each device. [link]https://macaddresschanger.com/what-is-bluetooth-address-BD_ADDR

Answer (score 1):

Design your `BLE` hardware with your defined `UUID`. And inside your mobile apps, search available devices using BLE Apis on this `UUID` only, using filter. This will return only devices having your `UUID` in BLE range, not others.

```
List<ScanFilter> filters = new ArrayList<>();
    ScanFilter scanFilter = new ScanFilter.Builder()
          .setServiceUuid(ParcelUuid.fromString(YOUR_OWN_UUID))
          .build();
    filters.add(scanFilter);
    // Start scanning on your UUID
    mBluetoothLeScanner.startScan(filters, settings, mScanCallback);
```

Ref : [Example](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=android.bluetooth.le.ScanFilter)